# jQuery only working on first event on page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

The following jquery will only alter the '#switch1' html the first time the checkbox is clicked, so I'm not sure why it doesn't go through the conditional the second time the action is taken.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#switch1 .switch').click(function(){
    if($(this).prev().is(':checked')){
      $('#switch1').html('<input class="switch" type="checkbox" name="auth_service_twitter" value="0"/>Twitter');}  

    else{
        $('#switch1').html('<input class="switch" type="checkbox" name="auth_service_twitter" value="1" checked="checked"/>UTwitter');}});});
</script>

<form id='socialForm' action='' method="post">
  <ul id="switch1">
    <input class="switch" type="checkbox" name="auth_service_twitter" value="0"/>Twitter
  </ul>
</form>
```

Comment: I added a `live` version as you requested... [check it](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9890869/601179)

Answer (score 0):

:)... You override all the DOM under the switch `ul` with `$('#switch1').html(...`

solutions:

1. Use delegate event.
2. Don't delete all the DOM...

[**LIVE DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/ejzW4/) of delegate events:

```
$('#switch1').on('click', '.switch', function() {
    if (!$(this).is(':checked')) {
        $('#switch1').html('<input class="switch" type="checkbox" name="auth_service_twitter" value="0"/>Twitter');
    } else {
        $('#switch1').html('<input class="switch" type="checkbox" name="auth_service_twitter" value="1" checked="checked"/>UTwitter');
    }
});​
```

---

**Update:** you wrote your's jQuery version is `1.4` so... use `live` :( this way:

```
function handler(){
    if (!$(this).is(':checked')) {
        $('#switch1').html('<input class="switch" type="checkbox" name="auth_service_twitter" value="0"/>Twitter');
    } else {
        $('#switch1').html('<input class="switch" type="checkbox" name="auth_service_twitter" value="1" checked="checked"/>UTwitter');
    }

}

$('#switch1 .switch').live('click', handler);
```

​
**[Live DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/ejzW4/8/)**

Comment: the .on seems to work with jquery 1.7.1, not with jquery 1.4 (which I am using, and I was hoping not to change that because I am using a lightswitch plugin within the form that requires 1.4...)

Answer (score 0):

Try using live() for binding instead of click. click() events are assigned to the objects present when the page loads, and since you replace the elements with html() the assignment is lost.

BTW, why not use $('.switch').attr('checked','checked') (and change the value the same way) instead of replacing all the HTML? Should be more robust.

Comment: the `live` function is deprecated. (it isn't the guy since jQuery 1.4.4. So enough with that `live` dude. **:)**)

Comment: You're right of course, he should use on() instead. But it doesn't change the fact that he needs to move away from click() to something that doesn't affect only objects present at load time.

Comment: Yep. to `on`... :) see my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You were overwriting the original `checkbox` hence destroying it's event handler.

See http://jsfiddle.net/xDNKe/1/ for a working implementation.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use delegate/on function:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function()
{
    $('body').on('click', '#switch1 .switch', function()
    {
        if (!$(this).is(':checked')) {
            $('#switch1').html('<input class="switch" type="checkbox" name="auth_service_twitter" value="0"/>Twitter');
        } else {
            $('#switch1').html('<input class="switch" type="checkbox" name="auth_service_twitter" value="1" checked="checked"/>UTwitter');
        }
    });
});
</script>

<form id='socialForm' action='' method="post">
  <ul id="switch1">
    <input class="switch" type="checkbox" name="auth_service_twitter" value="0"/>Twitter
  </ul>
</form>
```